# Swift 3 - distinguishing between "for loops"

Tags: for-loop, swift3

I am trying to figure out the difference between the following:

```
for i in A {
```

and

```
for i in 0..<A.count {
```

Don't they both just iterate through the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift has only one `for` loop, unlike some other languages. Swift's for loop iterates over a `Sequence` and provides (in the loop variable, `i` in your case) each element of that sequence.

In your first example, the sequence is `A`, the array itself, which means that `i` is an element of the array:

```
var A = [ "Mal", "Wash", "Kaylee" ]
for i in A {
    print(i) // prints "Mal" on the first pass, then "Wash", then "Kaylee"
}
```

In your second example, the sequence is a `Range` of integers, starting at zero and ending at one less than the size of the array. So `i` is an integer:

```
for i in 0..<A.count {
    print(i) // prints "0", then "1", then "2"
}
```

If you're using the second style and you need the array element, you need to explicitly fetch it from the array in the loop body:

```
for i in 0..<A.count {
    print(A[i]) // prints "Mal", then "Wash", then "Kaylee"
}
```

This can be useful for situations where you care at least as much about indices as content:

```
for i in 0..<A.count {
    if A[i] == "Wash" {
        A.insert("Zoe", at: i + 1)
    }
}
```

Although, if you need both the elements and indices in a sequence, the preferred Swift style is to use `enumerated()` instead — this provides a sequence of tuples, giving you both:

```
for (index, element) in A.enumerated() {
    print(index, element) // prints "0 Mal", "1 Wash", "2 Kaylee"
}
```

Comment: Is your first loop example interchangeable with the third example?

Comment: Those two snippets have the same effect, yes. Whether the two forms are interchangeable in general depends on what else you might try to do in the loop body.

Comment: If you're just comparing a variable to the elements in the array, regardless of the indices, then they would be interchangeable?

Comment: Yes — `for element in array { /* read element */ }` and `for index in 0..<array.count { /* read array[index] */ }` are equivalent. Swift developers tend to favor concision, though, so if you don't have a use for `index` other than fetching `array[index]` it's generally better to prefer the first form.